# Are GET Parameters Search Engine Indexable?

Tags: php, html, seo

I have coded a web directory that uses GET to generate all pages of information from a database. Is it possible for these pages to be indexed individually by a search engine?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you can link directly to it, then a search engine can index it (unless you take other steps to explicitly exclude them).

Comment: Ok, just a technical question now. How exactly do I do this for say Google?

Comment: Publish the site on the Internet. Don't keep it a secret. Wait for Google to follow a link to it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be sure to remember this for next time. It seems there was no information regarding this anywhere.

Comment: @Rilee: URLs are URLs, regardless of whether they have query strings.